# Merge files using a common column (awk)

Tags: awk, text

I have two text files:

file 1:

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT
1   61442   rs2531261   A   G
1   924629  rs28622096  A   G,T
1   974662  rs2465135   G   T
1   995481  rs9442393   T   G
```

file 2

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT FORMAT
1   61442   rs2531261   A   G   GT:GL:GQ:DP:CGA_RDP:EHQ:HQ:CGA_CEGL:PS:CGA_CEHQ:AD
1   924629  rs28622096  A   G,T GT:GL:GQ:DP:CGA_RDP:EHQ:HQ:CGA_CEGL:PS:CGA_CEHQ:AD
1   974662  rs2465135   G   T   GT:GL:GQ:DP:CGA_RDP:EHQ:HQ:CGA_CEGL:PS:CGA_CEHQ:AD
1   987909  rs34235844  G   GTG GT:GL:GQ:DP:CGA_RDP:EHQ:HQ:CGA_CEGL:PS:CGA_CEHQ:AD
1   995481  rs9442393   T   G   GT:GL:GQ:DP:CGA_RDP:EHQ:HQ:CGA_CEGL:PS:CGA_CEHQ:AD
```

I would like to combine the files based on column 3 (ID). My output file should like:

output:

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT FORMAT
1   61442   rs2531261   A   G   GT:GL:GQ:DP:CGA_RDP:EHQ:HQ:CGA_CEGL:PS:CGA_CEHQ:AD
1   924629  rs28622096  A   G,T GT:GL:GQ:DP:CGA_RDP:EHQ:HQ:CGA_CEGL:PS:CGA_CEHQ:AD
1   974662  rs2465135   G   T   GT:GL:GQ:DP:CGA_RDP:EHQ:HQ:CGA_CEGL:PS:CGA_CEHQ:AD
1   995481  rs9442393   T   G   GT:GL:GQ:DP:CGA_RDP:EHQ:HQ:CGA_CEGL:PS:CGA_CEHQ:AD
```

I want to use `awk`.

Comment: What information is in `file 1` that is not already in `file 2`? It's not clear from your question.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to *filter* file2 based on the IDs in file 1 (rather than *merge* the files):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$3] = 1; next} $3 in a' file1 file2
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT FORMAT
1   61442   rs2531261   A   G   GT:GL:GQ:DP:CGA_RDP:EHQ:HQ:CGA_CEGL:PS:CGA_CEHQ:AD
1   924629  rs28622096  A   G,T GT:GL:GQ:DP:CGA_RDP:EHQ:HQ:CGA_CEGL:PS:CGA_CEHQ:AD
1   974662  rs2465135   G   T   GT:GL:GQ:DP:CGA_RDP:EHQ:HQ:CGA_CEGL:PS:CGA_CEHQ:AD
1   995481  rs9442393   T   G   GT:GL:GQ:DP:CGA_RDP:EHQ:HQ:CGA_CEGL:PS:CGA_CEHQ:AD
```